# Use zoom level beyond 21 on iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am displaying some floor plans using GMSPolygons within the google maps SDK for iOS.  On our web-based version, we can switch to map type "None" and zoom beyond the max zoom level to view fine details of the floor plans.

Within iOS if I specify the map type kGMSTypeNone and use [_myMapView setMinZoom:16 maxZoom:25] I am still unable to zoom past 21.

Is there a workaround for this?